# How to find blank within Category in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find "Order Number" of the Customer that has been designated a Driver but not for that Order Number. if you see in the screen shot attached

[image]

You can See "Ray" that has no Designated Driver as well,but since none of his Orders has been designated a Driver ,I am not looking to get him ,in the following case only trying to get "James" with Order "15"
Please help
Thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far? Can you share your code

Comment: Since you are trying, please share what did you try so far. Not as an image, please. Will be impossible to copy-paste your code for us to test any possible solution.

Comment: read through this and see if you can get some help doing it yourself. https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/.  Also search Stack Overflow for similar questions. There are many questions that answer this

Answer (score 0):

Given csv as per screenshot (data.csv):

```
name,address,order_num,driver
james,ny,12,rod
james,ny,13,rod
ray,ny,14,
james,ny,15,
cody,ny,16,rod
ray,ny,,
```

You can groupby customer (name) and then apply filter where
1 -  at least one order has empty driver
2 - not all driver is empty

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
g = df.groupby("name").filter(
    lambda s: s["driver"].isna().values.any() and not all(s["driver"].isna())
)
print(g[g["driver"].isna()])
```

and get the following:

```
    name address  order_num driver
3  james      ny       15.0    NaN
```